# Converting 25 hours (DST) to datetime

Tags: python, timezone, dst

DST has just been executed this weekend. Hence, one day has 25 hours.

I have some data for each day. Basically, just one value for each hour, e.g:

```
df =

index     val
-------------
 0         1
 1         2
 2         4
 3         8
 4         16
 5         20
 6         12
 7         3
 8         5
 9         2
10         29
11         4
12         9
13         11
14         15
15         30
16         40
17         7
18         19
19         4
20         2
21         1
22         1
23         20
```

I can usually convert an hour to a datetime by doing:

```
import pytz
import datetime as dt

cph = pytz.timezone("Europe/Copenhagen")
dates.append([cph.localize(dt.datetime(year, month, day, i, 0, 0)) for i in range(24])
```

And then I can add this to the dataframe instead of the current index.

However, for these DST days, there are 25 values. And apparently when I try to do the above, but with `range(25)` instead, I get the error:

```
ValueError: hour must be in 0..23
```

So it seems like I can't do DST with `dt.datetime`, or at least not the way I am doing it.

So yeah, how can I fix this ?

Comment: First you'll need to know when exactly DST change happens. Then for the times where DST is not applied, use "CET" time zone while for the times where DST is applied, use the "CEST" timezone. Afterwards, convert to UTC and perform all your operations exclusively in UTC.

Comment: There's a lot of "it depends" on this one actually.  1) Do the days need to be normalized to a local time zone, or could they be UTC days? 2) Is there only one time zone for all data, or could there be many? 3) If there is overlap between two hours, what is your business logic? (sum? average? something else?)  4) Have you considered the opposite direction, when there could be only 23 hours in the day? 5) Have you considered that some time zones are 30-minute offset or 45-minute offset from UTC?  6) Have you considered there's one time zone that only switches by 30 minute for DST?