# creating datetime from date string plus hour offset not working across DST boundary

Tags: python, datetime, dst

I'm in the early stages of learning Python, and I'm struggling to get DST time changes handled properly. I have CSV data that has a date column and an hour column and I am trying to create a timezone-aware datetime from that. The CSV data is in US Eastern Standard Time (prevailing) but the data itself does not contain this information.

So for November 3, 2024 (the date of the fall time change), we'll have 25 hours. My date field will simply be '2024-11-03' and the hours field will range from 0 to 24.

Using the content from [Specify timezone when loading using datetime.strptime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68029638/specify-timezone-when-loading-using-datetime-strptime), I tried this:

```
for i in range(25):
    dt = datetime.fromisoformat('2024-11-03').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
    dt += timedelta(hours=i)
    print(dt.timestamp() , '->' , dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'))
```

which results in:

```
1730606400.0 -> 2024-11-03 00:00:00 -0400
1730610000.0 -> 2024-11-03 01:00:00 -0400
1730617200.0 -> 2024-11-03 02:00:00 -0500
1730620800.0 -> 2024-11-03 03:00:00 -0500
...
1730692800.0 -> 2024-11-03 23:00:00 -0500
1730696400.0 -> 2024-11-04 00:00:00 -0500
```

Not quite right.

If I do the almost identical code in PHP (which I'm proficient in) I get the expected result:

```
1730606400 -> 2024-11-03T00:00:00-04:00
1730610000 -> 2024-11-03T01:00:00-04:00
1730613600 -> 2024-11-03T01:00:00-05:00
1730617200 -> 2024-11-03T02:00:00-05:00
...
1730689200 -> 2024-11-03T22:00:00-05:00
1730692800 -> 2024-11-03T23:00:00-05:00
```

So clearly my method here in Python doesn't like the time change itself. So I tried converting to timestamps and manually adding seconds, but it doesn't work either:

```
for i in range(25):
    dt = datetime.fromisoformat('2024-11-03').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
    dt = dt.fromtimestamp(dt.timestamp() + i*3600).replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
    print(dt.timestamp() , '->' , dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'))
```

I also saw this: [Converting 25 hours (DST) to datetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74260817/converting-25-hours-dst-to-datetime), but it didn't seem to solve my issue either.

I'm sure there must be a simple solution here...

**EDIT:** in addition to Michael Cao's solution, which I accepted, I found another using pytz, in case this helps anyone else:

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from pytz import timezone

eastern = timezone('America/New_York')
for i in range(25):
    dt = eastern.normalize(eastern.localize(datetime.fromisoformat('2024-11-03')) + timedelta(hours=i))
    print(dt.timestamp() , '->' , dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'))
```

Comment: It's best to do all your timedelta math on UTC times, and convert back to local time at the end. See for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74291715/python-using-timedelta-around-dst-hour. As the top answer there says, *"timedelta arithmetic is wall time arithmetic"*.

Comment: Returning to your overall problem of parsing the CSV. How does your input file deal with the DST transition? You say *"the hours field will range from 0 to 24"*. Does this mean that for the DST fall-back day, there are two rows with `hours=1` and you infer that the first is 0100 summer time, the second is 0100 winter time?

Comment: @slothrop, I have seen that implemented in some of the other sources I've parsed. It's a pain in the A$$. In this case, the "hour" column isn't intended to be true to the hour, rather an offset from the date. So on a non-time change day, you'll have the hour(offset) column run from 0 to 23. On the spring time change it will be 0 to 22, and fall time change from 0 to 24.  The easiest way to parse it is to take the date at hour = 0, convert to UTC, then add houroffset*3600. I tried that in Python as well (code at the bottom of my question) unsuccessfully. Michael Cao did what I was trying

Comment: Right I see. In that case though, hopefully @MichaelCao 's answer will work for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found success in converting the datetime to utc first then adding the timedelta then converting back to EST.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from zoneinfo import ZoneInfo

for i in range(25):
    dt = datetime.fromisoformat('2024-11-03').replace(tzinfo=ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
    dt = dt.astimezone()
    dt += timedelta(hours=i)
    dt = dt.astimezone(ZoneInfo("America/New_York"))
    print(dt.timestamp() , '->' , dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S %z'))
```

Output:

```
1730606400.0 -> 2024-11-03 00:00:00 -0400
1730610000.0 -> 2024-11-03 01:00:00 -0400
1730613600.0 -> 2024-11-03 01:00:00 -0500
1730617200.0 -> 2024-11-03 02:00:00 -0500
1730620800.0 -> 2024-11-03 03:00:00 -0500
...
1730692800.0 -> 2024-11-03 23:00:00 -0500
```

Comment: Ah, perfect. I was trying to do something similar in the code at the bottom of my question, but this works!

Comment: why not do the timedelta arithmetic in UTC instead of some random timezone that `.astimezone()` gives you, depending on the machine you run the code on? See e.g. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76858711/10197418).